# delete hive partitioned external table but retain partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, metadata

When using external hive tables, is there a way where I can delete the data within the directory but retain the partitions via a query.  Please note I dont want to drop the table and recreate it.  I just want to empty the underlying folder and start a process all over again. My tables are large, with partitions by year, month, date and hour and it takes a lot of time to recreate partitions manually.

Thanks

Comment: write a loop in shell and delete files inside partition folders.

Comment: Thats what I did, curious to know if there is a query that does it.

Comment: No such query afaik. Drop partition will remove partition from metadata, not files, insert overwrite partition is not efficient anyway. Removing files works efficiently.

Comment: How do you remove your data? i think `hdfs dfs -rm -r mytable/year=*/month=*/date=*/*` should work

Comment: @leftjoin - check my answer

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz In your case there are two commands: alter + truncate, or even three, one more alter to revert back to external instead one rm command for each partition using shell

Comment: @leftjoin - so? would you prefer to check for the table location (assuming that all the partitions are located under the same root and all the paths have the same structure) and than initiate a `dfs -rm` command under the risk that you may have a typo?

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz Yes ! Partitions can be located under different roots. It's quite possible and your solution makes sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`truncate table ...` to delete all data.
`truncate table partition (...)` to delete specific partitions' data.

The directories structure is kept.

---

External table should be first converted to manged, .e.g

```
alter table t set tblproperties('EXTERNAL'='FALSE');
```

When we done, we can convert it back

```
alter table t set tblproperties('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');
```

---

#### Demo

```
create table t (i int) partitioned by (x char(1));
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
insert into t partition (x) values (1,'A'),(2,'B'),(3,'C');
alter table t set tblproperties('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');
```

---

```
select * from t;
```

---

```
+-----+-----+
| t.i | t.x |
+-----+-----+
|   1 | A   |
|   2 | B   |
|   3 | C   |
+-----+-----+
```

---

```
dfs -ls -R /user/hive/warehouse/t;
```

---

```
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2017-03-28 11:40 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=A
-rwxrwxrwx   1 cloudera supergroup          2 2017-03-28 11:40 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=A/000000_0
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2017-03-28 11:40 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=B
-rwxrwxrwx   1 cloudera supergroup          2 2017-03-28 11:40 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=B/000000_0
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2017-03-28 11:40 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=C
-rwxrwxrwx   1 cloudera supergroup          2 2017-03-28 11:40 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=C/000000_0
```

---

```
truncate table t partition (x='B');
```

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10146]: Cannot truncate non-managed
>   table t.

```
alter table t set tblproperties('EXTERNAL'='FALSE');
```

---

```
truncate table t partition (x='B');
```

---

```
select * from t;
```

---

```
+-----+-----+
| t.i | t.x |
+-----+-----+
|   1 | A   |
|   3 | C   |
+-----+-----+
```

---

```
dfs -ls -R /user/hive/warehouse/t;
```

---

```
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2017-03-28 11:40 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=A
-rwxrwxrwx   1 cloudera supergroup          2 2017-03-28 11:40 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=A/000000_0
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2017-03-28 11:42 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=B
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2017-03-28 11:40 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=C
-rwxrwxrwx   1 cloudera supergroup          2 2017-03-28 11:40 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=C/000000_0
```

---

```
truncate table t;
```

---

```
+-----+-----+
| t.i | t.x |
+-----+-----+
```

---

```
dfs -ls -R /user/hive/warehouse/t;
```

---

```
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2017-03-28 11:43 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=A
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2017-03-28 11:43 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=B
drwxrwxrwx   - cloudera supergroup          0 2017-03-28 11:43 /user/hive/warehouse/t/x=C
```

---

```
alter table t set tblproperties('EXTERNAL'='TRUE');
```

Comment: Dudu, question is for external tables.

Comment: @franklinsijo, I'll check in a minute but it is a non-issue since we can change external to manged and vice versa.

Comment: @David דודו Markovitz - nice.. don't we need to run msck repair after this operation.

Comment: @vikrantrana - No need. `truncate table` works on the files level (delete files) while `msck repair table` works on the directories level (looks for gaps between the existing folders and the defined partitions)